# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (200,200,3) into shape (200,200)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

[ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (200,200,3) into shape (200,200)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rTcj.png)

```
img_000= np.array(img_00)
```

Comment: Your `img_00` is a list of arrays.  My guess is that some are color with shape (200,200,3) (or 4), and others b/w with shape (200,200) or (200,200,1).  `np.array` cannot make a 4d array from such a mix of shapes.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
np.asarray(img_00)
```

your image needs 3 channels: (width, height,colorchannels)

Comment: I try reshape but they don't work

Comment: What error does `reshape` give?  Did you try to apply it to whole list, or to component arratpys?

Answer (score 0):

A small example that displays a similar error

```
In [72]: alist = [np.ones((3,3,3)), np.zeros((3,3))]

In [73]: np.array(alist)
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7196\2629805649.py:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array(alist)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [73], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.array(alist)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3,3) into shape (3,3)
```